# Show that all the roots of $p(z)$ are in $\bar{D}(0,c+1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z)=a_0+a_1z+ \cdots + a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+z^n$, and $c=\max\{{|a_0|,|a_1|,\dots, |a_{n-1}|}\}$. Show that all the roots of $p(z)$ are in $\bar{D}(0,c+1)$.

I am trying to prove this and I have no idea where to start. I tried a concrete example so I could see what was going on but that didn't really help me write up a proof for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clear if $c=0$, so assume $c>0$.

If $|z|=c+1$ then
$$ |a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}|\leq c+c(c+1)+\dots+c(c+1)^{n-1}=c\frac{(c+1)^{n}-1}{(c+1)-1}$$
$$=(c+1)^{n}-1<(c+1)^{n}=|z|^{n}$$

Therefore you can apply Rouche's theorem to conclude that all of the zeros of $p(z)$ lie in the disk $|z|<c+1$.

Comment: No need to use Rouché, since a slight change in the inequality chain shows that $|p(z)|\ge|z^n|-|a_0+…+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}|\ge 1$ for $|z|>1+c$.